# Purchase SSL certificate for kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, amazon-eks

My service (with no ingress) is running in the amazon EKS cluster and I was asked to provide a CA signed cert for a third party that consumes the API hosted in the service. I have tried provisioning my cert using certificates.k8s.io API but it is still self-signed I believe. Is there a CA that provides certification for services in the Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Certificates created using the certificates.k8s.io API are signed by a [dedicated CA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/#configuring-your-cluster-to-provide-signing). It is possible to configure your cluster to use the cluster root CA for this purpose, but you should never rely on this. Do not assume that these certificates will validate against the cluster root CA.

Refer this [Certificate Signing Request Process](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/)